# Get current height or line count of a TextField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to measure the height or the current line count of a TextField in Flutter. The height could be different depending on the device screen.

```
TextField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        minLines: 5,
        autofocus: true,
        controller: storyController,
        onChanged: (text) {
          onStoryTextChanged(text);
        },
        cursorColor: Colors.black,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          fillColor: Colors.transparent,
          filled: true,
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
        style: textStyleNormalOnPaper,
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it from onchanged event of textfield

```
onChanged: (val){
   print('\n'.allMatches(val).length);
    },
```

**Edit**

```
TextSelection _selection = TextSelection(baseOffset: 0, extentOffset: text.length);
List<TextBox> lines = textPainter.getBoxesForSelection(_selection);
print(lines.length);
```

Comment: There is a problem that only new lines that the user has entered in the text field are counted. Automatic new lines that occur due to the limited width of the screen are unfortunately not counted.

Comment: Example: A user enters a very long text of 1000 words without creating a new line. Then the text is wrapped due to the limited width of the screen and the number of lines of the text field increases. This is not computable with this solution.

Comment: @laprof have you found this solution if yes kindly share..